# NSXMLDocument validateAndReturnError requires network connection?

Tags: cocoa, xsd, nsxml

I am trying to validate an XML Schema document against the schema for schemas (http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema) using NSXMLDocument. I've gotten it to work correctly, and assumed that I was validating against a local schema.

However, I discovered that without a network connection, this validation doesn't work. Is there any way to force NSXMLDocument to use a local schema for validation?

The code I have working with a net connection:

```
xmlDoc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:furl            options:(NSXMLDocumentValidate | NSXMLNodePreserveAll)
                                                    error:&err];
NSXMLElement *rootElement = [xmlDoc rootElement]; 
NSMutableArray *namespaces = [[rootElement namespaces] mutableCopy];
[namespaces addObject:[NSXMLNode namespaceWithName:@"xsi" stringValue:@"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"]];
[rootElement setNamespaces:namespaces];
[rootElement removeAttributeForName:@"xsi:schemaLocation"];
[rootElement addAttribute:[NSXMLNode attributeWithName:@"xsi:schemaLocation" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema %@", @"/System/Library/Schemas/XMLSchema.xsd"]]];
BOOL vaildXML = [xmlDoc validateAndReturnError:&err];
```

The schema tag of the document I'm validating:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:myCompany="http://schema.myCompany.com/SomeSchema"
targetNamespace="http://schema.myCompany.com/SomeSchema">
```

It seems to be having a problem with the w3.org schema location, but not my company's.

The error I'm seeing

error : No such file or directory
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd"

Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=1 UserInfo=0x103051c10 "Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}import': Failed to locate a schema at location 'http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd'. Skipping the import.
attribute use (unknown), attribute 'ref': The QName value '{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang' does not resolve to a(n) attribute declaration.
attribute use (unknown), attribute 'ref': The QName value '{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang' does not resolve to a(n) attribute declaration.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Apple docs for the [NSXMLDTD](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDTD_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class suggests that you do have access to catalogs. However, there seems to be very limited support for defining the catalog to be used. Either you can create a catalog at `/etc/xml/catalog` or set the `XML_CATALOG_FILES` environment variable.

Once you've got a catalog, you should be able to place an entry into it for the W3 schema along with a local copy. Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD Entity Resolution XML Catalog V1.0//EN" 
    "http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/release/1.0/catalog.dtd">
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">
  <system systemId="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd" uri="xml.xsd"/>  
  <uri name="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" uri="xml.xsd"/>
</catalog>
```

This assumes that you have the catalog and the schema in the same directory.

I can't try this myself (lack of time and rusty Cocoa skills) but it should work. If I remember correctly, NSXML is based on libxml2 which certainly supports catalogs.
The specifications for catalogs themselves can be found on the [OASIS website](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=entity).